# In Perl, how does the || operator work?

Tags: perl

So here are the

```
$y = 0 | 2 | 4;  # answer is  6

$x = 0 || 2 || 4;  # answer is 2
```

I know why `$y` is `6` because it's using the `OR` operator on each number and `2 | 4 = 6` but for `$x`...

Why is it `2`?

Comment: Also see the documentation: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-Or-and-Exclusive-Or versus http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#C-style-Logical-Or.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because 2 is the first non-falsy item and a logical OR short circuits.  It evaluates zero which is false, then 2 which is not false so it is done and returns 2.  Consider the output of the following example:

```
$val = 1;
sub a_proc {
    print "a_proc: ", $val++, "\n";
    1;
}
$another_val = &a_proc || &a_proc;
```

This will output `a_proc: 1`.  As soon as `a_proc` returns a true value, the interpreter can stop evaluating since a logical OR of `true` and any value is `true`.

Comment: Actually, doesn't it process the statement like so: `(0 || 2) || 4`? Meaning that it actually does two computations, but short-circuits the second.

Comment: @TLP, short-circuiting refers to the *operands* not getting evaluated. Since there are 2 binary operators, there are actually 4 operands. The LHS of both `||` are evaluated, but only the RHS of left-most `||` is evaluated. 1) `0||2` is evaluated. 2) `0` is evaluated. 3) `2` is evaluated. 4) `4` is not evaluated due to short-circuiting (the LHS, `0||2`, returned true).

Comment: @ikegami I know what short-circuiting means. My point was that with a line of `||` compared statements, perl does not look ahead and say "Oh good, the rest of the line is only more `||` comparisons, I can short-circuit here." It does actually recognize and evaluate the second `||`, which is then short-circuted accordingly. A true value would that way "fall through" an entire chain of `||` statements, but the chain itself is not short-circuted.

Comment: @TLP - ikegami is correct.  The interpreter stops evaluating as soon as it has true value.  I'll edit in an example that shows this.

Comment: @D.Shawley Yes, I tried that myself. What I am after here is what happens when there are multiple `||` linked together. Does perl recognize the entire chain of statements as one and short circuit right away, or does it go through them all (always only checking the LHS). I know it's a rather useless knowledge, really, but I am curious.

Comment: @TLP - Perl like most languages parses the source into an abstract representation (usually an [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)).  The interpreter evaluates the tree.  When processing a logical OR, it evaluates the left subtree and only evaluates the right subtree if the left one is false.

Comment: @TLP - It doesn't even look at the right branch of the OR unless the left branch is `false`.  It really isn't useless knowledge.  I've found that an understanding of parsing and interpretation of a syntax stream incredibly useful.

Answer (score 8):

Its a short-circuiting, value-preserving logical or.  Basically, it evaluates each of the things between the `||` in turn, until it finds one that is not false, at which point it returns that one and doesn't evaluate any subsequent operands.

**edit**

There are two important features of perl's logical ops

- they are *short circuiting* in that they evaluate the left operand first, and it if it is true (false for `&&`) do NOT evaluate the right operand
- they are *value preserving* in that they convert the operand to a boolean true or false for the conjunction (and to determine whether to evaluate the right operand), but the result of the expression is the original value before the conversion to boolean

Both of these features are very important and they combine to make `||` particularly useful in perl -- much more so than in C/C++ where it is just short-circuiting and NOT value preserving.

Comment: This is particularly relevant if the operands are function calls for performance and side effects (or avoidance thereof).

Comment: Logical AND also short-circuits and is used to test def'ness of variables.  defined $var && doSomethingWith($var) This keep doSomethingWith() from trying to process an undef'd variable.

Answer (score 5):

**While the operators look similar, their purpose is actually different.**

From [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-Or-and-Exclusive-Or):

> Binary "||" performs a short-circuit
>   logical OR operation. That is, if the
>   left operand is true, the right
>   operand is not even evaluated.

Compared to:

> Binary "|" returns its operands ORed
>   together bit by bit.

The purpose of `||` is to come up with an answer to "is `x || y` true or false?", while the purpose of `bitwise or` - `|` - is to come up with a product (?) of operands, or something like "what is the result of `x | y`?"

Since the only interesting two results from `||` is true or false, the statement can (and is) short-circuted, thereby causing this effect.

In the first statement:  `(0 | 2) = 2, (2 | 4) = 6`

In the second statement: `(0 || 2) = 2, (2 || ...) = 2`

Interestingly, `bitwise or` is setting boolean values inside a binary number. Adding a true or false value on the positions within the binary representation of the number.

```
0000 | 0010 = 0010
0010 | 0100 = 0110
0110 | 0001 = 0111
0111 | 0001 = 0111 # no change
```

Which is very handy for storing multiple boolean values in one number, which can be checked with the `&` (`bitwise AND`).

```
0101 & 0100 = 0100 (true)
0101 & 0010 = 0000 (false)
```

*There are 10 kinds of people: Those who understand binary numbers, and those who don't.*

Comment: Bitwise OR is never used for comparison.  It's purpose is to calculate the bitwise OR of two bit patterns.  It is also not binary addition - it is simply a bitwise OR.  The only comparison that might appear to happen is the implicit comparison against zero.

Comment: @D.SHawley Have I said that it was?

Comment: Ah I see. Fixed. I was struggling for words.

Answer (score 2):

```
EXPR_A || EXPR_B
```

is more or less equivalent to

```
do { my $rv = EXPR_A; if ($rv) { $rv } else { EXPR_B } }
```

Or in English,

1. First, it evalutes EXPR_A in scalar context.
2. If value is true, this value is returned.
3. If the value is false, EXPR_B is evaluated and returned.

Sometimes you'll see them chained.

```
EXPR_A || EXPR_B || EXPR_C || EXPR_D
```

is just

```
( ( EXPR_A || EXPR_B ) || EXPR_C ) || EXPR_D
```

so just apply the above recursively.

You end up with the result of the first expression that returns true, or the result of the last if none are true.